# Allocate uncacheable memory to access directly to ram

Tags: c, memory, ram

I'm trying to measure access time to RAM.

I have read that the "mtrr" allows declare "uncachable" address ranges.

My question is how can i access to those memory locations from a C program.
All related threads i found are about using "uncachable" memory to access IO devices, never to RAM locations, what makes me think..

is it possible to declare a range of the ram memory "uncachable"?

and if so, how can i access it from a C program running in user mode?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do declare a memory range as uncacheable using gcc on x86 platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412169/how-do-declare-a-memory-range-as-uncacheable-using-gcc-on-x86-platform)

Comment: Since this is a question about hardware access from an application you should probably tell us what operating system you are using.