# Are there any such processors which have instructions to bypass the cache?

Tags: assembly, x86, processor, cpu-cache, instructions

Are there any such processors which have instructions to bypass the cache for a specific data? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544094/c-working-with-the-cpu-cache) also has an answer which suggests that SSE4.2 instructions do bypass the cache. Can somebody enlighten me on that?

Comment: I am curious:  What practical application is there for bypassing the cache?  All that comes to mind is improving the predictability of instruction timing.  Are there others?

Comment: 2 cases I commonly encounter are sharing time-sensitive data between threads running on different cores, and writing to memory-mapped registers to interface with other hardware (such as a UART IC)

Comment: @wallyk: The typical purpose is to prevent cache pollution (e.g. if you're writing a lot of data and don't expect to read any of it "soon", and don't want the data you will need to get pushed out of the cache).

Comment: Yes, many processors provide instructions to bypass cache. See my detailed [survey paper on cache bypassing techniques](https://www.academia.edu/24842555/A_Survey_of_Cache_Bypassing_Techniques) for CPUs, GPUs and CPU-GPU systems. It also discusses benefits, challenges and tradeoffs of bypassing.

Answer (score 5):

In general, the caching policy is controlled by the Memory Management Unit (MMU). For each address range, a caching policy is decided upon. These tables are managed by the OS and are available in system space.
As a sidebar answer to a question that you may have intended to ask, for architectures that have a cache, there are usually CPU commands available for synchronizing/invalidating/flushing the cache. However, much as the MMU tables, these commands are also available only in system space.

Comment: Slight clarification; on x86, the `clflush` instruction (to invalidate a _single_ cacheline) is _not_ privileged. And, as the original poster mentioned, the `movnt` SSE instructions allow cache-bypassing _stores_ - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070/what-is-the-meaning-of-non-temporal-memory-accesses-in-x86 for details.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any such processors which have instructions to bypass the cache for a specific data?

The SuperH family (or at least the SuperH-2) has both implicit and explicit bypassing of its cache memory. This is done by using different areas of the memory address space, rather than through special instructions.
By setting the top 3 bits of an address to `001` you would access a *cache-through* mirror of the same address with the top 3 bits cleared. And some areas (like memory-mapped I/O registers) are never cached.

Answer (score 2):

Altera Nios II architecture has 2 specific instructions `ldio` and `stio` for loads/stores that bypass the cache. They're used for memory-mapped IO.

http://www.csun.edu/~glaw/ee525/Lecture03Nios.pdf

Nios II is a soft processor generally used for Altera's FPGA boards and although it can also be licensed for hard ASIC devices but I don't know any commercial CPUs based on this architecture

Answer (score 2):

The SSE cache-bypass store instructions are to avoid polluting the cache when writing to a region that won't be touched again soon.  e.g. you don't want to evict data that will be used again.

Also, x86 implementations normally read in a whole cache line when a write into any part of the cache line occurs.  If the previous contents of the cache line are unneeded, this is a waste of memory bandwidth.  (e.g. the `dest` arg of `memcpy` or `memset`.)  I found [some old discussion](http://svn.0x00ff00ff.com/mirror/package/avisynth/x86/FilterSDK/IsMovntqFaster.htm) of this write-back (default) vs. write-combining (`movntq` / `movntdq`) effect for implementing `memcpy`.  Be careful of using this if something else will read the output of `memcpy` right away.

Streaming loads only work for [reading from USWC regions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/copying-accelerated-video-decode-frame-buffers), as normal `memcpy` performs horribly in that case.  Streaming loads from normal (WB (writeback)) are currently not special, and work like regular `movdqa` loads.  (i.e. the NT hint is ignored).  Intel's optimization manual says you can use `prefetchnta` for pollution-reducing loads.

---

IDK if it's possible to write into cache (rather than bypassing with `movnt`) without triggering a read.  Possibly AVX512 will solve this problem for `memcpy`, because a 512b ZMM register is 64bytes, i.e. a full cache line.  A 64-byte aligned store from a ZMM register to memory that wasn't already cached *could* be implemented in a way that didn't read the RAM first, and still made the store visible right away to other CPU cores in the system.

([AVX-512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512) is going to be in [Skylake Xeon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_%28microarchitecture%29) (not other skylake CPUs).  Also in [Knight's Landing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_Landing_(microarchitecture)), the massively-parallel high-throughput Xeon Phi compute accelerator thing.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of specific data, yes. Processors generally have cache control registers / tables which are used to define what regions of memory can be cached vs. which must not be cached. Generally, code running in user space is not able to access those tables.