# Does x86 provide instructions to load which data goes into cache?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

There are prefetch instructions as mentioned here: https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_252.html which  allows a system program to HINT the cpu as to which data SHOULD go into the cache. But, if is a single simple program loaded by the bootloader as an operating system - something as simple as MikeOS - then, can these hints make this almost certain as to which data  sits on cache since only a single process is dictating the cpu - or still the cpu is doing branch predictions on its own? Does it mean that cpu's internal branch prediction is prefered for this purpose?

Comment: Don't think so, no. Besides, the performance penalty of allowing it would probably far outweigh any gains. How would you ensure that your caching policy is the best for all CPU architectures, all cache sizes, etc?

Comment: x86 has [`prefetch` instruction](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_252.html), but usually the CPU is smart enough to recognize access patterns itself, so you would have to measure carefully the performance to see if it truly helps, or just adds useless opcode into the binary.

Comment: @fredrik Thanks for your comments, but could you expand a little bit on what could be some performance penalties?

Comment: The most common performance penalty is bad algorithms. It sounds like you're aiming for something that would almost certainly be premature optimization

Comment: yes. x86 SSE and NIOS II are some examples. Possible duplicate of [Are there any such processors which have instructions to bypass the cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17093509/995714)

Comment: since this is such a wide open question (not a stackoverflow question) the answer is absolutely.  If you are in control of the processor and understand the architecture then you can control most if not all of what is in the caches.  Even when not completely in control you can encourage things to be in cache but you are competing with other code and if you dont know/understand the other code or what it is doing it determines how little control you may have.

Comment: You should ask a real question, and be more clear as to what you are after. Need to specify your architecture, system, and operating system.  And at that point you can just look up the answer.  Caches simply respond to what the bus tells them to do.  If running an operating system like windows, linux, etc you have an mmu that in part controls which address spaces are cacheable, which is mostly if not completely driven by the operating system.  despite that though you could do some striping at the application level to erase things in cache that you have read.  if lucky

Comment: if this is yet another I meltdown/spectre question, this is not how you work around them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any such processors which have instructions to bypass the cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093509/are-there-any-such-processors-which-have-instructions-to-bypass-the-cache)

Comment: x86 has `clflush` and `prefetch` instructions to evict or cache specific cache lines, but usually caches work fine on their own (with HW prefetch, or simply from demand loads bringing data into cache), with an LRU eviction strategy.

Comment: don't make an edit that makes the meaning of the question changes significantly. If you have a different question, ask another one

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: The first version of the question was not useful or interesting.  Your rollback invalidated my answer.  Perhaps this question is just unsalvageable, though.

Answer (score 2):

The branch-target buffer (and other branch-prediction caches like the branch history buffer) are totally separate from the L1D / L1I / L2 / L3 memory caches.

x86 has no instructions to manage the branch-prediction caches, only the data / instruction caches (which is what most people mean when they just say "cache").  AFAIK, no other architectures have cache-control instructions for the branch prediction caches either, but you seem to be only discussing x86.

I'm also not sure whether you're actually trying to ask about the branch-prediction caches or whether you're just totally confused about how CPUs work.  See [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf) by Ulrich Drepper,  and a 2017 update on a few minor points. 
 [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126311/what-every-programmer-should-know-about-memory/47714514#47714514)

This is pretty much all it's possible to say in response to such a mixed-up question, apart from the links in comments about controlling the contents of the data / instruction caches (which as I said is what most people mean when they talk about loading data into caches).