# How can i disable cpu cache for certain memory regions?

Tags: c, linux, caching

I read on wikipedia that disabling cpu-cache can improve performance:

> Marking some memory ranges as non-cacheable can improve performance, by avoiding caching of memory regions that are rarely re-accessed.

When I googled how to do it in c on linux however, I didn't find anything. It's not that I really need this feature but I'm interested anyways.

And do you know of any projects which use this optimization?

Edit: I'm programming for x86_64

Comment: This is highly platform dependent. What platform are you programming for?

Comment: Your question seems to be answered here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544094/c-working-with-the-cpu-cache

Comment: @Abstraction The answer pertains Windows, but OP is using Linux. Also, wrong language.

Comment: @FUZxxl only the most voted answer is about Windows. The second and the last answers are relevant to OP's question.

Comment: @FUZxxl One answer pertains to Windows and C++. Another [details GCC cache bypass intrinsics](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9544581/1899640) in C for Linux.

Comment: @thatotherguy The answer you link is not an answer as per policy as it does not explain anything, it only links to material without citing the relevant parts. Such answers are wrong according to site policy. I don't see OPs question answered in a satisfied manner anywhere.

Comment: This question is not asking for an off-site resource or a library. Why is it being closed as such? You are strange people.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to allocate, in user space, a non cacheable block of memory on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885658/is-it-possible-to-allocate-in-user-space-a-non-cacheable-block-of-memory-on-li)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That comment about non-caching doesn't mean what you think it means, and where it is used, it isn't usually a user-accessible feature. That is, CPU cache control is typically a privileged operation.

That said...

-- A normal user program can be build with functions who's attributes are "hot" or "cold" to let the compiler tell the loader to group the functions in ways that will utilize the cache most usefully.

-- A normal program can use the madvise() function in linux to tell the paging function various things, including the fact that the memory just used is or is not likely to be used again soon.

-- The kernel itself uses the Memory Type Range Regesters (mtrr) and Page Attribute Table (pat) flags in later kernels, to tell the hardware that particular ranges of memory (such as the memory mapped display buffer, and the various parts of the PCI bus) are not to be cached.

"Normal Data™" such as you are likely to use in any C program will *essentially* never benefit from marking any of its data not cache-worthy. The performance improvement that not-cached data enjoys is the subsequent absence of the various cache-flush and memory barrier operations that memory mapped devices and display buffers would need almost constantly. Laying a cache over a memory mapped device, for example, would require a cache invalidate command before every read and a cache forced write command after every single write to make sure that the reads and writes happen at the exact moment needed. This would "poison" the cache usage, using up and instantly discarding cache lines (a physically limited resource) in a most unfriendly and unhelpful way.

In the rare case that you write a program that gains access to one of these cache harmful regions -- such as if you wrote part of the X display server on a linux system -- the kernel would have already set the registers for the device and the non-cache behavior would be transparent to you.

There is effectively no time where your normal application grade program is going to benefit from any ability to mark a variable as harmful to cache beyond the various madvise() type of usage.

Even then, the cases were you could gain *any* benefit are so rare that if you'd ever acutally run into one, the problem set would have included the need and methodology as part of your research and you'd have been told how and why so explicitly you'd never have needed to ask this question.

To go back to the same example again, if you'd been writing the necessary driver, when you'd been reading up on the display adapter hardware or the PCI bus the various flags and techniques would have been documented and discussed in the hardware guide.

There are ways to pull off cache ejection and such from user space with things like the CLCLEAR instruction on an intel platform. These techniques will *not* improve general performance.

Since it's a privileged operation on a Linux system, you *could* write a kernel driver that acquired and marked a region of memory as uncacheable and then let you map it into your application. But the need for such a region is so rare, and so likely to be misused, that there isn't a normal methodology for doing it in place.

So how do you do it? You don't, at least not the you that you are today. When you become a kernel driver writer with an intimate specialty knowledge of multi-threaded code and data synchronization issues, you'll know how you could do it, and at that point you'll know why you don't want to except as a last resort.

TL;DR :: because of the way linux uses and manages data and code, there is never a benefit for marking any part of a normal application as uncacheable that doesn't cause more heartbreak than it saves. As such, there is no unprivileged API for doing this.

P.S. Also, that said, someone already pointed to things that lead to this article http://lwn.net/Articles/255364/ which covers ways to make your program very cache friendly and some of the ways that you can do some cache bypass operations very cheaply. For instance use of memset() tends to go around the cache while setting memory, and some operations can "stream past" the cache. This isn't the same thing as what you ask, but once you understand all of that article you'll have a much better understanding of why marking a region of memory as uncachable is usually, as the Jedi say, not the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Recently i needed to experiment with uncached memory in a cache-heavy multi-threaded application.

I came up with this [kernel module](https://github.com/lemonsqueeze/uncached_ram_lkm) which allows to map uncached memory to userspace.

User process requests uncached memory by calling mmap() on module's character device (see test directory for demo).

[What every programmer should know about memory](https://lwn.net/Articles/250967/) is indeed a must read !

Comment: Interesting! It would be good to try a write test using a set_memory_wc() write combining region.

Comment: Your malloced memory might be hot in cache before testing starts. It would be interesting to get the cacheable memory from raw operating system virtual memory allocation functions, perhaps choosing the virtual address yourself, and/or flushing the cache by doing a r/w over a second large buffer immediately before timing begins.

Comment: A more representative test would be one in which you have hot data you want kept in the cache and cold data which you access non-coherently.